# Changing data in registration form

Tags: forms, email, phpbb3

Where may I find file in which I could edit variable called L_USERNAME_EXPLAIN to view additional info in registration form? 
I try in common.php but there is no variable called like that.

I've got some problems with sending email from admin account, some hosts don't want to received it from me but with another (like gmail.com) everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the L_USERNAME_EXPLAIN variable is.... variable (I know that doesn't make sense!). It all depends on your ACP settings under 'User registration settings'

If you open `/language/xx/ucp.php` (where xx is the language you use, eg the default English is en ) and look around line 476 you will see various explanations for different username configurations....

```
'USERNAME_ALPHA_ONLY_EXPLAIN'   => 'Username must be between %1$d and %2$d chars long and use only alphanumeric characters.',
'USERNAME_ALPHA_SPACERS_EXPLAIN'=> 'Username must be between %1$d and %2$d chars long and use alphanumeric, space or -+_[] characters.',
'USERNAME_ASCII_EXPLAIN'        => 'Username must be between %1$d and %2$d chars long and use only ASCII characters, so no special symbols.',
'USERNAME_LETTER_NUM_EXPLAIN'   => 'Username must be between %1$d and %2$d chars long and use only letter or number characters.',
'USERNAME_LETTER_NUM_SPACERS_EXPLAIN'=> 'Username must be between %1$d and %2$d chars long and use letter, number, space or -+_[] characters.',
'USERNAME_CHARS_ANY_EXPLAIN'    => 'Length must be between %1$d and %2$d characters.',
```